# How to bind an Object's attribute to a hidden field using ThymeLeaf?

Tags: java, html, thymeleaf

**HTML - ThymeLeaf Template:**

```
<form th:action="@{/gustos}" method="post" th:object="${gusto}">
    <div class="col s12 l8">
                    <select th:field="*{categoria}">
                        <option value="" disabled="disabled">Categoria</option>
                        <option value="Dulces de Leche">Dulce de Leche</option>
                        <option value="Cremas">Cremas</option>
                        <option value="Chocolates">Chocolates</option>
                        <option value="Frutales">Frutales</option>
                    </select>
    </div>
</form>
```

This are my Java **Gusto** class attributes:

```
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private int id;

    @Column
    private int idCategoria;

    @Column
    private String categoria;

    @Column // opcional (name="")
    private String nombre;
```

I need the **int idCategoria** value in my **Gusto** class to take the value of 1 if the first option (Dulce de Leche) is selected by the user, 2 for the second one, 3 for the third one, and 4 for the forth one but I don't know how to do this with ThymeLeaf !! This logic is based on the **categoria** attribute , if categoria equals a certain name, then the categoriaId will be a certain number ... EXAMPLE: if categoria equals 'Dulces de Leche' the categoriaId should be '1' !!!

¡ Notice I'm using object binding at the top of the form !

I've tried this:

```
  <div th:field="*{idCategoria}">
            <div th:switch="*{categoria}">
                <input type="hidden" th:case="'Dulces de Leche'" value="1" />
                <input type="hidden" th:case="'Cremas'" value="2" />
                <input type="hidden" th:case="'Chocolates'" value="3" />
                <input type="hidden" th:case="'Frutales'" value="4" />
            </div>
  </div>
```

but it's not working !!! I wanna do the logic in the template !!

How can I do it ?

Thanks all a lot <3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `jQuery` to accomplish this. Just create a new hidden input, with the field you are missing. Your code would looking like the following bit.

**First your new input and category's select changes**

```
<input id="id" th:field="*{id}" hidden="hidden"/>
<select id="categorias" th:field="*{categoria}">
    <option value="" disabled="disabled">Categoria</option>
    <option value="Dulces de Leche">Dulce de Leche</option>
    <option value="Cremas">Cremas</option>
    <option value="Chocolates">Chocolates</option>
    <option value="Frutales">Frutales</option>
</select>
```

**Now your jQuery**

```
$('#categorias').on('change', function() {
    var value = $(this).val();
    if(value === "Dulce de Leche") {
        $('#id').val(1);
    }
    // Now you just fill the rest.
})
```

So now, every time you change your category, you will add a new value to the id. Hope it helps! If you need anything else, please, let me know.

Comment: Thank you Alain !!! This logic seems good, I don't know why I get lang.IllegalArgumentException: Can not set int field com.uces.CopitoDeNieve.model.Gusto.idCategoria to null value ----> message error

Comment: That is because we are setting `null` to an int, which is a primitive. You are getting this after submitting the form or when parsing? If you are getting it while submitting, then you could add `th:value=0` to the id input. Of course, you would need to check afterwards that your id is not 0.

Comment: Yep, I'm getting it after submit ... I'll try with this option now !

Comment: My last fix will only avoid the `lang.IllegalArgumentException`, but you are still not getting the right value though. It means that we are not setting the right value in our `jquery`. I made a typo in my answer, I wrote **Dulce de Leche**, instead of `Dulces de Leche`. That could cause trouble.

Comment: Still null ... even with the S added to Dulces de Leche ... this is getting weird :(

Comment: Opps change `*{id}` for `*{idCategoria}`. Just realized I was using the wrong field.

Comment: I'd changed it before cause I saw the error, but still null

Comment: <div class="col s12 l8">
        
                <input id="id" th:value="0" th:field="*{idCategoria}" hidden="hidden"/>
                <select id="categorias" th:field="*{categoria}">
                    <option value="" disabled="disabled">Categoria</option>
                    <option value="Dulces de Leche">Dulce de Leche</option>
                    <option value="Cremas">Cremas</option>
                    <option value="Chocolates">Chocolates</option>
                    <option value="Frutales">Frutales</option>
                </select>
            </div>

Comment: Do you mind adding your Controller method? I wanna check out how you are doing the binding.

Comment: This is the method that handles that view    @RequestMapping(value="gustos/add")
    public String formNewGusto(Model model){
        model.addAttribute("gusto", new Gusto());
        return "form";
    }

Comment: Ok, this is the one you use to load the page. I mean the one where you are sending your post. The one that is mapped to `/gustos` and should be of type `POST`.

Comment: Sorry :)   @RequestMapping(value = "/gustos", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public String addGusto(Gusto gusto){
        gustoService.save(gusto);
        return "redirect:/gustos"
    }

Comment: The crazy thing is that the other fields are working fine ... they display as expected in the DB, but not this one :(

Comment: Well it shouldn't make a difference, but let's see if it works. Change it for the following. `@RequestMapping(value = "/gustos", method = RequestMethod.POST) public String addGusto(@ModelAttribute("gusto") Gusto gusto){ gustoService.save(gusto); return "redirect:/gustos" }`. Yeah it is odd, since you are even adding a default value to it.

Answer (score 0):

Try this out:

```
<select th:field="*{categoria}">
    <option th:value="" disabled="disabled">Categoria</option>
    <option th:value="1" th:text="Dulces de Leche"></option>
    <option th:value="2" th:text="Cremas"></option>
    <option th:value="3" th:text="Chocolates"></option>
    <option th:value="4" th:text="Frutales"></option>
</select>
```

This way, when you retrieve the values through your backend, it would either be 1, 2 or 3

Comment: Thanks for the answer ... I still need the th:field="*{categoria}" values for this too !!! Is there a way to get two values from the th:field and bing them to different attributes ?

Comment: Maybe I'm not making myself clear ... sorry :(
I need what you put as th:text to be binded to another attribute from my Gusto object (in this case it's the "categoria" attribute). That is working ok ! What I need is to bing ANOTHER value, the 1, 2, 3, and 4 values to the attribute "idCategoria" .... Can I pass more than one value to the th:field ? So I can then have two th:value and bing the first parameter with the first th:value and the second parameter with the second th:value ??

Comment: Maybe something like this ?? <select th:field="*{categoria, idCategoria}">    
                        <option value="" disabled="disabled">Categoria</option>
                        <option th:value="Dulces de Leche" th:value="1">Dulce de Leche</option>
                        <option th:value="Cremas" th:value="2">Cremas</option>
                        <option th:value="Chocolates" th:value="3">Chocolates</option>
                        <option th:value="Frutales" th:value="4">Frutales</option>
                    </select>

Comment: You cannot pass more than one value to an option (hance why it is called an option). You can work it around by using some logic in your java class. Try to use IF STATEMENTS as in something like htis ==> If value is Dulces de Leche, create new variable and give it a value of one....

Comment: !!! Why is this not working ?? <input type="hidden" th:field="*{idCategoria}" th:if="*{categoria == 'Dulces de Leche'}" th:value="1"/>   I really need to do this in the template sheet

Comment: Neither this:         <div th:field="*{idCategoria}">
            <div th:switch="*{categoria}">
                <input type="hidden" th:case="'Dulces de Leche'" value="1" />
                <input type="hidden" th:case="'Cremas'" value="2" />
                <input type="hidden" th:case="'Chocolates'" value="3" />
                <input type="hidden" th:case="'Frutales'" value="4" />
            </div>
        </div>

Comment: Just use java to retrieve values and check if the value equals -for example Dulces de Leche - initiate a new String variable with the value 1 and so on...

Comment: It's not that easy cause I'm using Spring ! That's why I wanna do it in the template ... don't know where to put the logic for this in Spring :/

Comment: What do you have in your Spring Controller ?

Comment: @RequestMapping(value="gustos/add")
    public String formNewGusto(Model model){
               model.addAttribute("gusto", new Gusto());
        return "form";
    }

Comment: That is the method that returns the view for the form